# rpm -Uvh authenticated proxy access ... just hangs?

Tags: proxy, rpm

I'm not sure how to set up authenticated proxy access with rpm. But I have it set up with wget and yum.

When I run rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/etc...

It just says 'Retrieving http://...' and I have no idea what's going on.

Any help?

Comment: I think the simple answer is you CAN'T. You have to download the repo from wget / yum and then rpm -Uvh the repo without http'ing.

Answer (score 4):

For RPM, what you provide to `--httpproxy` will be forwarded to `curl --proxy`.

So `rpm --httpproxy http://foo:bar@proxy.example.com:3128`.

If you want to troubleshoot, you can edit `/usr/lib/rpm/macros` and remove `--silent` in there:

```
%__urlhelpercmd         /usr/bin/curl
%__urlhelperopts        --silent --show-error --fail --location -o
%__urlhelper_proxyopts   %{?_httpproxy:--proxy %{_httpproxy}%{?_httpport::%{_httpport}}}%{!?_httpproxy:%{nil}}
```

Comment: This is working! export http_proxy just work for the rest except rpm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the usual way of exporting the http_proxy (and/or https_proxy) variable. I believe this will also work with "wget". RPM seems to use "curl" to get the files, so "man curl" may be also useful.

```
$ rpm -qp http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/6/os/i386/Packages/centos-release-6-2.el6.centos.7.i686.rpm
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2001:200:141:feed::feed: Network is unreachable
error: http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/6/os/i386/Packages/centos-release-6-2.el6.centos.7.i686.rpm: open failed: No such file or directory

$ export http_proxy="http://${proxy_user}:${proxy_pass}@${proxy_server}:${proxy_port}/"
$ rpm -qp http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/6/os/i386/Packages/centos-release-6-2.el6.centos.7.i686.rpm
centos-release-6-2.el6.centos.7.i686
```

Comment: tried this to no avail

Comment: Can you indicate what OS or rpm version you are on? The example I gave is something that I actually did try.